# Open Method of Worksheet fails

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I do not understand why there is this error in my VBScript:

```
'Déclaration des variables
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, CurrAddin
'Création des Objets
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

For Each CurrAddin In objExcel.AddIns
    If CurrAddin.Installed Then
        CurrAddin.Installed = False
        CurrAddin.Installed = True
    End If
Next CurrAddin

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\rd\python_scripts\private_bank_mini3.xlsx")
'Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\rd\python_scripts\Test.xlsx")

'Pause de 10 secondes
WScript.Sleep 10000
'Pause de 8 heures
'WScript.Sleep 28800000

'Enregistrement
objExcel.EnableEvents = False
objWorkbook.Close False
objExcel.EnableEvents = True

'Fermeture de Excel
'objExcel.Quit

'Désallocation mémoire 
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing

'Fermeture du Script
WScript.Quit
```

Please find below my error messages:

[image: Error message1]

My script works with the file "Test.xlsx" but not with the "private_bank_mini3.xlsx", the difference between those is the charging of a Add-In at the opening of the second file.

Have you got an idea to manage it please?

Comment: which line does the error appear on? you can step through your code by pressing the F8 key

Comment: Set objWorkbooks2 = WScript.GetObject("C:\rd\python_scripts\private_bank_mini3.xlsx") , needs fully qualified path name of the file that contains the object persisted to disk.

Comment: but why do you need those pauses?? process is synchronous, workbook.open wont start executing until previous one, objExcel.EnableEvents = False, is finished anyway...

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment tsolina:
"needs fully qualified path name of the file that contains the object persisted to disk"

Comment: instead "private_bank_mini3.xlsx" this "C:\rd\python_scripts\private_bank_mini3.xlsx", so complete path

Comment: Sorry, so according you this following line is wrong ?
Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\rd\python_scripts\private_bank_mini3.xlsx")

Comment: No, @tsolina is saying that the `Set objWorkbooks2 = WScript.GetObject("private_bank_mini3.xlsx")` is wrong

Comment: But my problem is with the Open function:
Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\rd\python_scripts\private_bank_mini3.xlsx")

Comment: Try to create a file with only the lines up to the `Set objWorkbook1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\rd\python_scripts\private_bank_m‌​ini3.xlsx")`. See if it works or you still get an error. Your code works just fine on my end

Comment: can you open that document manually?

Comment: Yes, but my file charge an Add-in and I think this is the problem. Because this code works with a file that doesn't use this Add-In. How can I manage it please ?

Comment: Which add-in does it trigger?

Comment: @VictorMoraes Doesn't matter. Add-ins must be loaded explicitly when instantiating Excel from a script. Possible duplicate of [Loading addins when Excel is instantiated programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213375/1630171).

Comment: Thank you. So in this case, how can we do this in VB Script please ?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the info, I've never had to load add-ins in Excel, so it is good to know that. Sebastian, Ansgar has provided a link with the answer to your question :)

Comment: Yes, but I am still confuse because the response a VBA script and I don't know how can I put it in my VBScript

Comment: Instead of the (implicit) `Application` object that you have in VBA use your (explicit) application object variable (`objExcel`) in VBScript.

Comment: I have update my code, but I don't understand how manage it

Comment: I think this is wrong (line 12): `Next CurrAddin`. Comment out or otherwise remove the `CurrAddin`